# Unable to load DLL  XXX.dll, Can not find specified module.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.5

Recently I wrote a small winForm program using `C#` language. In the app I use `C#` to invoke a "*.dll" file written in `C++`. It works all right in my `Visual Studio 2012` and on my computer, but when I move it to other computer, it always pops an error about  **“ Unable to load DLL  ' *.dll',can not find specified module.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).  ”**.

I've searched the internet for solution. There are also some similar questions regarding problems that others met and it seems that they also have not found the right solution yet. I also tried some methods like moving my '*.dll' file to `windows\system32` or write the app current directory to `System Enviroment Variable`, but this also didn't work.

Now I really don't know how to deal with it. So I'll be very appreciative if someone could give some help.

I'm new here and thanks very much.

Comment: You seem to be missing a dependent dll on the other computer. Check the dependency of the dll in that machine using a tool such as dependency walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Have a look at this question with regards to the dependency suggestion above: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10774250/31770

Comment: I use dependencywalker to check the dependency of the dll,and find two dll missed, then i download them and move them to windows\system32. Also I register them, but my app still can't work..

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old post but shows up first in Google so I am gonna post my solution to the issue: I was writing a minimal DLL in C++ which I integrated in a minimal C# console application and got the same error that you stated above. The final fix is simple: Your target PC might not have the appropriate VS redistributable package installed. In my case (VS 2013) it was this one here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 for some reason it does not work to copy the required DLLs from the system32 folder manually... what a freak bug taking me half a day to find out. I did not find this anywhere online, will do some cross-posting now...