# C++ written dll and C# call

Tags: c#, c++, dll

After a long reading time I didn't get the dll working...
I tried so much different ways but no way worked..

I did the following things: (IDE: VS2013Ultimate)

1. I added a clean c++ project. There I added 1 header file [header.h]:

   ```
   #pragma once

   class myClass{
   public:
       myClass(double varx, double vary);
       double sumxy();
   private:
       double x;
       double y;
   };
   ```
2. I added a body.cpp file:

   ```
   #pragma once
   #include "header.h"

   myClass::myClass(double varx, double vary){
       x = varx;
       y = vary;
   }

   double myClass::sumxy(){
       return x + y;
   }
   ```

   That's all the code I would need. I only want a working example code.
3. I added one class [main.cpp]:

   ```
   #include "header.h"  
   #include "body.cpp"  

   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double sumxy(double var_x, double var_y){
       myClass MC(var_x, var_y);

       return MC.sumxy();
   }
   ```
4. After this I compiled this dll and I got it without any compile errors. `I copied it to the debug folder of the c# Console Application
5. C# Console Application:

   ```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   //all using directories

   namespace Klassen_Tester {
       class Program {
           [DllImport("CppClassDll.dll")]
           public static extern double sumxy(double var_x, double var_y);

           static void Main(string[] args) {
               Console.WriteLine(sumxy(3, 5).ToString());

               Console.ReadLine();
           } 
       }
   }
   ```

Please help me. Don't know what to do.. And sorry for my bad english.

Edit: There is an error: System.DllNotFoundException in Klassen_Tester.exe. DLL "CppClassDll.dll" could not be found. HRESULT: 0x8007007E) could not be load.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: First of all, **never** use absolute paths in a `DllImport` attribute. Put `CppClassDll.dll` in the same directory than the C# console exe, and use `[DllImport("CppClassDll.dll")]`. Same thing about `#include`. The isue is that `\U` for instance in a string gets transleted to `U` (the backspace is the escaping character and is ignored in front of a character that does not need escaping)

Comment: Yeah i did this before... But i didnt work also.. so i searched other examples.. this is the last one i found..

Comment: I did it all in one Project (c++ side) then i compiled it and copied into the debug path of c# project and then i changed the path of dll to the only string and then i started the C# project again and it says: "System.DllNotFoundException" Couldnt load dll

Comment: Is a DllMain required for C# interop?

Comment: It could be that it is required.. I dont know, thats why i am asking.. Its the first dll i am writing..

Comment: Is your C++ library [manifested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774250/dllnotfoundexception-with-hresult-0x8007007e-when-loading-64-bit-dll#comment14010912_10774451) @Leorus?

Comment: How could i check it? @GSerg

Comment: If you click that link and read the next comment, it asks just that, and then the next comment answers it.

Comment: Generate Manifest "Yes(/MANIFEST)" <- do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. So if it's not the manifest, then use ProcMon to see exactly what is not found, [as suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10774451/11683).

Comment: I installed procmon but how is it to handle?

Comment: Start it, provide a condition that matches your program's process, run your program, find relevant errors in the huge list procmon will generate (most likely will be related to some flavour of CreateFile).

Comment: Could you help me please via teamviewer >.<?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an interop between C++ and C# so you don't have to mess with pinvoke. I'm not saying pinvoke is bad but interops are nice.

You are going to want to write a CLR wrapper to act as an intermediary between the managed and unmanaged code. It looks like you have the C# and C++ mostly written so I'll describe the CLR portion.

1. Create a CLR project in Visual Studio
2. Add your native C++ project as a reference
3. Write your wrapper
4. Add reference to CLR project from C# project
5. Call CLR wrapper

Create a class with your C++ signatures likes this:

```
namespace YourWrapper
{

    public ref class WrappedFunction
    {

        public:

            // Adjust according to your c++ class and function
            double sumxy(double a, double b) {
                return myClass::sumxy(a, b);
            }       
    };

}
```

For a full example, see my project https://github.com/corytodd/interop-example: